# How to save and delete image with name in Photo Library in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem to save image in photo library with name. I am using code like this to save image in photo:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(Imagename.image, nil, nil, nil);
```

This code save image in photo library but not with name

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.png"];
        NSLog(@"File Path =%@",filePath);
        // Save image.
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(Imagename.image) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

This code save image with name but in directory not in photo library.

I need to save image in photo library with name and also need to delete it if it is already save in photo library.

Comment: Have you looked into using the Photos framework (PHPhotoLibrary and related classes)?

Comment: @maddy I need to delete image also?

Comment: @maddy Can you please share some code how to do this?